# Confusion regarding defining ordered pair in form of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was reading this book called "discrete maths by susanna epp"
The topic of representing ordered pair by sets came in which it was done by

$$ \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \} = (a, b)$$

In a set order doesn't matter

**My question is isn't this also valid?**
$$\{ \{b, a\}, \{a\} \}=\{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \}? $$
if yes, then $\{ \{b, a\}, \{a\} \}$, $b$ comes first, then $a$ so how come $ \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \} = (a, b)$ be valid?

Comment: You are right that in "a set order doesn't matter."  So look carefully at the definition (and presumably the explanation given in that book on discrete math) and try to see how the first element of the ordered pair might be determined without resort to the order (arrangement) in the set notation of elements.

Comment: The "decoding" of this ordered pair has been discussed here before.  It helps to know that it is commonly called [Kuratowski's ordered pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767604/please-explain-kuratowski-definition-of-ordered-pairs).

Comment: The first element is not whatever you write first. The first element is the unique element of $\cap(a,b)$.

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the order you write the elements of the set doesn't matter. So instead, consider that in both cases one of the element of the set is a subset of the other, which *does* create an ordering of the elements. In both the case of $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ and $\{\{a, b\}, \{a\}\}$, you can pick the "first" element as being $\{a\}$ since $\{a\} \subseteq \{a, b\}$ but $\{a, b\} \not\subseteq \{a\}$ unless $a = b$.